# Percentile of sum of random variables

Tags: statistics, percentile

There appears to be some similar questions, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222314/exact-percentile-of-random-variables-sum). However, none got answered. Hence, I would like to ask the following question:

Say $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are three random variables (not $i.i.d.$) and $Z=X+Y$. Then is there any relationship between percentiles of $Z$ and percentiles of $X$ and $Y$, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, quantiles of sums of random variables are difficult. Even for small discrete samples useful results are difficult to find.

For example, if I know the sample means and sample sizes of two samples $x_i$ and $y_i$ of respective sizes $n,$ then I can find the mean of sample $z_i = x_i + y_i$  as $\bar z = (\sum_i x_i + \sum_i y_i)/n.$

However, I know of no similar relationship for the median. As a trivial example, the sum of 
$x = (1, 2, 3, 14, 15)$ and $y = (1, 2, 3, 14, 15)$ has vastly different
quantiles than the sum of
$x' = (1, 2, 3, 14, 15)$ and $y' = (15, 14, 3, 2, 1).$
[You might be able to get some useful results for sums of *order statistics.*]

*Notes* (1) The general intractability of combining quantiles is one reason the
US Census Bureau is willing to release *median* incomes for census tracts, but (to protect individual privacy) not *mean* incomes.

(2) There are some perhaps tangentially related results. For example, if $X_i$ are i.i.d
from a continuous population whose density function $f$ is positive in the vicinity of the median $\eta,$ then the sequence of sample medians $\tilde X_n$ is asymptotically
normal with mean $\eta$ and asymptotic variance $[4nf(\eta)^2]^{-1}.$ And
similar theorems apply for $p$th percentiles with $0 < p < 1$ (but not
for maximums and minimums). [One reference is Bain & Englehardt (1992) p244.]