# Percentiles of sums of random variables

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, percentile

Heads up, I'm asking this question after having read [Percentile of sum of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157925/percentile-of-sum-of-random-variables) and other questions. Please don't close this as a duplicate. It's not the same question.

Suppose I have two positive random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, and the following percentiles or upper bounds on them. The joint probability assumes independence.

\begin{aligned}
P(X_1<35) &= 0.95 \\
P(X_2<40) &= 0.95 \\
P(X_1<35, X_2<40) &= 0.95^2
\end{aligned}

$X_1$ is concentrated beneath $35$, and $X_2$ beneath $40$. They're both under their respective limits with probability $0.0925$. That means that their sum can not reach $\ge70$ with $p=0.0925$, right? How can I prove this? I have a feeling I'm wrong. I know I'm skipping steps, yet don't know the steps.

$$P(X_1+X_2<35+40) = 0.95^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't. Because it is not true.

Because it is possible to get less than 75 in other ways also. For example, 10+65 = 75.

$$P(X_1+X_2<35+40) = 0.95^2 $$
$$\implies P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1<35 \land X_2<40) $$$$+ P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1<35 \land X_2\ge40) $$$$+ P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1\ge35 \land X_2<40) $$$$+ P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1\ge35 \land X_2\ge40) $$$$= 0.95^2$$

In this, the fourth term is obviously 0.

In the fist term, $X_1<35 \land X_2<40 \implies X_1+X_2<35+40$. So the first term becomes $P(X_1<35 \land X_2<40)$ which is nothing but $ 0.95^2$.

Substituting the first and fourth term, we get
$$ 0.95^2 + P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1<35 \land X_2\ge40) $$$$+ P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1\ge35 \land X_2<40) +0 $$$$ = 0.95^2 $$

Which means
$$ P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1<35 \land X_2\ge40) + P(X_1+X_2<35+40 \land X_1\ge35 \land X_2<40) =0 $$

Which obviously not true.
What could be true is
$$P(X_1+X_2<35+40) > 0.95^2 $$

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I was going to ask if a lower bound was possible and you beat me to it. Very helpful!